# Experimental samples with rare earth metal

Tags: solid-state-physics, experimental-physics

Many experiments, such as optical, superconductivity, etc, use the samples that involve rare earth metals and transition metals. Why are they used that often. Is the main reasons:

1. They have the required electronic structure in its d- and f- orbital so that we can create the required spin-spin interaction.
2. They provide the required structure of the crystal
3. They provide the required energy band gap

Any elaboration?

**Edit**: Here the samples I mean is the usual YBCO, or some papers, say [Gd5Si2Ge2](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2102), that I do not have any idea. I am also curious about why they decide to investigate a particular compound in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the open d- and f-shells that make for very interesting physics, because it can introduce effects that dramatically depend on doping. Look up "Strongly Correlated Materials" for an overview.

Comment: Is the same reason true for non-supercondutor?

Comment: Yes. There are other interesting material properties that are strongly influenced by the open d- and f-shells. You can have materials with very exotic phases and phase transitions.